# Ubuntu MATE is opening all existing text files as executable

Tags: text

I have a lot of text files that I copied over from a NTFS volume which, when I open them in Ubuntu MATE 15.04 through the Caja file manager, open as executable and show the dialog box which asks me if I want to execute the file.

Is this a bug or normal behavior? This didn't used to happen in Thunar on Xubuntu.

Comment: Hint: and those files have the executable persmissions set on Caja and did not on Thunar? ;-)

Comment: I don't have Xubuntu installed now so it's hard to know for certain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is normal behaviour. Well sort of. Be careful with regards to NTFS. Those partitions  tend to be mounted as executable making all files ... executable.

This one-liner will remove execute from .txt from the directory you execute it:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.txt" -exec chmod -x {} \;
```

When a text file has executable permissions set or is recognized as executable generally it will ask for it to be executed or to be viewed.

Nautilus also has a setting for this in "Edit" "preferences" "Behavior". Caja has the [same option](http://forums.mate-desktop.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1965) (though I have not found an image for Caja).

[image]

Comment: What I'm unclear about is whether the permission is being set when I copy it over in Ubuntu MATE or whether it was already set like that. I copied the files over from a NTFS volume, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: @warsong depending on how it was mounted, NTFS partitions can have *everything* marked as executable, so that might be the culprit.

Comment: @warsong you should have indeed. see the edit ;-)