# Ubuntu claims "executable text file" (e.g. .txt,.csv,.sh but not .xls) despite absence of `x` permission

Tags: permissions, nautilus, executable, text

When clicking on a file in my Ubuntu's file explorer Nautilus, for most types it asks me each time whether I want to run or view it. E.g. .csv, .txt, .sh, but not e.g. .xls (which readily opens with LibreOffce calc).

This, depsite my file *not* having the explicit executable permission `x` (and even if I explicitly use `chmod -x` before).

Why, and how to avoid it?

Note, this question has been answered for *textfiles* in *MATE*, [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/615282/874157). I post the general version here to possibly help others who like me struggle to readily find that or any other answer/question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/615290/874157) specifically given for the similar question for MATE and textfiles, applies, *at the very least mostly*:

- Solve it by: Nautilus -> Edit\Preferences\Behavior\ -> Choose "View executable text files ..." rather than "Ask each time"
- Origin of behavior (and further way to address the issue): Your drive file system may be NTFS or FAT[32] (including EFI). Neither support unix file permissions, meaning by default the whole volume gets mounted with execute permissions for all files. In `/etc/fstab` you can specify `noexec` as a mount option for the entire partition.

See further [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/nautilus-behavior.html.en) for more info on Nautilus preferences.

Comment: Note that neither NTFS nor FAT[32] (including EFI) support unix file permissions. In /etc/fstab you can specify noexec as a mount option for the entire partition.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that out. Btw, I reckon this does _not_ by chance explain also why I remain unable to change file associations on my machine (at least I'm unable to have .csv default to be playonlinux\Excel instead of LO calc), else I'm glad for a note. _Ignore if seems unrelated_

Comment: Please indeed update the part on "Origin of behaviour" with the comment of Siep. It is due to these file systems not supporting file permissions - hence the whole volume is by default mounted with execute permissions for all files.